# What is MAX number of domains can used in app_domains for my app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

What is MAX number of domains can used in app_domains for my facebook app ?
Needed to add more than 500 domain to my app

Comment: App Domains of Facebook App

Comment: _“Needed to add more than 500 domain to my app”_ – that is not possible. Mainly you can use _one_ domain for your app; using “hacks” such as using different domains for different platforms (website, page tab, canvas), you can increase the number a little – but you will definitively not be able to use 500 different domains. (Subdomains of one main domain would be a different matter.)